# Word Counting Class in Java Not Counting Every "That" That Appears

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a hashmap class in Java that counts every word that appears. It works for the most part but when I try using the paragraph:

> "They name the baby Susan. That manager found the box empty. Donna's daughter left the door open. That musician finds the book interesting. That dentist named the dog Fido"

It detects the correct amount of every other word except for "That". "That" appears three times in the paragraph but it only detects one "That". Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordCounts extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        HashMap<String,Integer> h = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        String input = readLine("Enter a string: ");
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
        {
            Integer num = h.get(words[i]);
            if( num == null)
                num = new Integer(1);
            else
                num = new Integer(num.intValue() + 1);

            h.put(words[i].toLowerCase(), num);
        }

        printSortedHashMap(h);
    }

    /*
     * This method takes a HashMap of word counts and prints out
     * each word and it's associated count in alphabetical order.
     *
     * @param wordCount The HashMap mapping words to each word's frequency count
     */
    private void printSortedHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount)
    {
        // Sort all the keys (words) in the HashMap
        Object[] keys = wordCount.keySet().toArray();
        Arrays.sort(keys);

        // Print out each word and it's associated count
        for (Object word : keys) 
        {
            int val = wordCount.get(word);
            System.out.println(word + ": " + val);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I accidentally wrote "that" instead of "That" in my description; what I meant was that I'm trying to figure out why the class doesn't count every "That".

Comment: Where are you removing punctuation?

Comment: Case matters.  "That" is not the same as "that".

Comment: You should add this as a test case: "I saw that!" --> you need to remove the "!", otherwise the 'word' will be "that!" and not "that".

Comment: As mentioned by @duffymo cases Do matter, also you may want to be splitting using more delimiters like split(" ,!.")

Comment: You never want to do `new Integer(1)`.  You should let Java do the auto-boxing for you because it is smart about using the same cached integer 1.  Just say `num = 1` or `num++`.

Comment: You should let the compiler autobox and unbox instead of using the `Integer(int)` constructor, it'll leverage the Integer cache (from -128 to 127) required by the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be a lot of things...
''That'' and ''that'' are not the same in java's eyes if you don't use `ignoreCase()`.
Also try to format your Strings with `StringTokenizer` it will make your life easier and your code shorter.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally wrote "that"; I'm trying to count every "That".

Comment: @BobSmith  you know you could use `StringTokenizer` instead of splitting your String to an array it will be a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue here is cause by these lines:

```
h.get(words[i])
```

and

```
 h.put(words[i].toLowerCase(), num)
```

You're looking for the words in your `HashMap` in their original case, but storing them in lower case.  So when you first see "That", you add it to the map as "that".  The next time you see "That", lo and behold, it's not in your map!  Because Java is case sensitive, and treats "That" and "that" as different strings.  So you re-add "that" to the map with a value of 1.  Rinse and repeat for every duplicate "That" that you see.

What you probably want to do is lowercase the entire input string before you start.  You likely also want to strip out all of the punctuation, so that words at the end of a sentence don't include the period.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the string key in lowerCase like you save it.

```
Integer num = h.get(words[i].toLowerCase());
```

Also you need to change the regex in the split method to get only the words :

```
String[] words = input.split("[ ,.?!:;]");
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to get rid of the period in the split method because when I ran the code it printed a bunch of the words with periods at the end. But after doing that, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the comments inline for your code, for updating the word count from the string array.

```
 for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {

// in the below line, while you are adding it to the map, the string was not converted to lowercase
        Integer num = h.get(***words[i].toLowerCase()***);
        if( num == null)
            num = new Integer(1);
        else
            num = new Integer(num.intValue() + 1);

// here you were doing it..
        h.put(words[i].toLowerCase(), num);
    }
```